# Reactor backpressure make publishing thread wait

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a single thread reading from SQS and want to publish each message onto a reactor processor with a single consumer. It's possible that the consumer will take up to 1-2s to process the message. I would like the publishing thread to wait if the consumer is busy. I would also like to parallelize the consumer but still keep the backpressure and slow down the publisher if all the threads are busy. Here is what I have so far but I dont see the publisher getting slowed down.

```
private EmitterProcessor<T> rp = EmitterProcessor.create(1);

void publish(T object) {
    rp.onNext(object);
}

void addConsumer(Consumer<T> subscriber) {
    ParallelFlux<T> flux = rp.parallel(workers, 1).runOn(Schedulers.parallel());
    if (backpressure) {
        flux.subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<T>() {
            @Override
            protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                request(1);
            }

            @Override
            protected void hookOnNext(T value) {
                subscriber.accept(value);
                request(1);
            }
        });
    } else {
        flux.subscribe(subscriber);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: who calls `publish(T)` in this example? backpressure is per-subscriber, and it might be better represented by something like `Flux.create(sink -> sink.onRequest(l -> generateSeveralElements(l)))`

Comment: @SimonBaslé can you point or provide us to a working example

Comment: see the snippet at https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create